# Subset specific rows per group

Tags: r, subset, slice, apply

I have a dataframe such that:

```
    Group     V2   V3   V4
      1        D    F    W 
      1        T    A    L 
      1        P    F    P 
      2        T    F    L 
      2        R    R    O 
      2        D    Y    L 
      2        D    F    I 
      ...
```

And I have list such that:

```
 [1]  1 3
 [2]  4
 [3]  2 3 4
```

Each element of the list indicates which row I want to keep for each group. So I only want to keep row 1 and 3 of Group==1 in the dataframe; the 4th row for the second group; rows 2 3 and 4 for the 3rd group etc.

I have tried hard but I haven't found a straightforward way although I'm pretty sure there must be one using apply or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) x[y,], split(df, df$Group), l1))
#    Group V2 V3 V4
#1.1     1  D  F  W
#1.3     1  P  F  P
#2       2  D  F  I
```

where,

```
l1 <- list(c(1, 3), 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the folowing objects to work with, a data.frame and a list, similar to yours:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Group     V2   V3   V4
      1        D    F    W 
      1        T    A    L 
      1        P    F    P 
      2        T    F    L 
      2        R    R    O 
      2        D    Y    L 
      2        D    F    I
      3        E    F    I
      3        F    F    I
      3        G    F    I
      3        T    F    I", header = T)
l <- list(c(1, 3), 4, c(2:4))

do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) df[df$Group == i,][l[[i]],]))
#   Group V2 V3 V4
#1      1  D  F  W
#3      1  P  F  P
#7      2  D  F  I
#9      3  F  F  I
#10     3  G  F  I
#11     3  T  F  I
```

yields the same result as the simpler data.table approach:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, .SD[l[[.GRP]]], Group]
```

or

```
dt[, .SD[l[[unlist(.BY)]]], Group]

#   Group V2 V3 V4
#1:     1  D  F  W
#2:     1  P  F  P
#3:     2  D  F  I
#4:     3  F  F  I
#5:     3  G  F  I
#6:     3  T  F  I
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_split(Group) %>% 
   map2_df(l, ~ .x %>% 
                  slice(.y))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Group V2    V3    V4   
#  <int> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1     1 D     F     W    
#2     1 P     F     P    
#3     2 D     F     I    
#4     3 F     F     I    
#5     3 G     F     I    
#6     3 T     F     I
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), V2 = structure(c(1L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 7L), .Label = c("D", "E", "F", "G", "P", "R", "T"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("A", "F", "R", "Y"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(5L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("I", 
    "L", "O", "P", "W"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

l <- list(c(1, 3), 4, 2:4)
```